# javascript dos funciones no deja ejecutarlas al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

```css
img{

  
  max-width:451px;
  width: 451px;
  height:254px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 100%;
  
   border-top-right-radius: 15px;
   border-top-left-radius: 15px;
   

}
#divimage div{
 width: 451px;
}
#wallet div{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

input{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>previe</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<body>
 
    
    <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" onchange="readURL(this);" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
    <label class="custom-file-label"  for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
  <div id="divimage">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  
   <div class="row">

   <img id="blah"  src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />

    <div id="quest" class="alert alert-warning col-12" role="alert"><p style="text-align: center;">
    ¿Con que frecuencia consume cafe?</p></div>
    
    <div class="alert alert-warning col-6">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning col-6">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>

   </div>

</div>
  

</body> 
</html>




<script type="text/javascript">
  
   function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

tengo estas funciones como hago para que puedan funcionar  las dos al tiempo

```js
    
function inputTexet(){
$("#texto1").on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#prueba").html(value);
    }).keyup();

}

 function inputTexet2(){
$("#texto2").on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#prueba2").html(value);
    }).keyup();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" name="texto1" id="texto1" onclick="inputTexet();" placeholder="escribe lo que quieras">
    <p id="prueba"></p>

    <input type="text" name="texto2" id="texto1"    onclick="inputTexet2();"  placeholder="escribe lo que quieras">
 <p id="prueba2"></p>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

El segundo `input` tiene el `id` igual al primero cambialo para que sea "texto2".

Resulta que el fallo está en que el segundo `input` tiene el mismo `id` que el primero, por eso cuando seleccionabas el segundo `input` con el `onclick` llamabas a la segunda función, pero como no encontraba el id no hacía nada.

---

Estás llamando las funciones con `onclick`, cuando con jquery ya se lo estás indicando

> No hace falta ya que `keyup` ya indica que si en el input se presiona
>   una tecla haga que en la etiqueta `<p>` se escriba.

```js
    

$("#texto1").on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#prueba").html(value);
    }).keyup();

$("#texto2").on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("#prueba2").html(value);
    }).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" name="texto1" id="texto1" placeholder="escribe lo que quieras">
    <p id="prueba"></p>

    <input type="text" name="texto2" id="texto2"  placeholder="escribe lo que quieras">
 <p id="prueba2"></p>
```

Comment: sigue igual compañero me sigue casando lo mismo

Comment: ¿No te funciona? Es raro por que el código que puse ejecutable es copiado del tuyo y solo hice lo que comente.

Comment: @RamonAlbares ¿Puedes editar tú pregunta y añadir tú código para ver donde está el problema?

Comment: listo ya lo hago

Comment: @RamonAlbares Perdona, pero...¿Cuál es el problema? Ya que has puesto otro código y no has explicado que está fallando. ¿Me podrías explicar cuál es el error?

Comment: ya muestro imagen para que veas

Comment: @RamonAlbares Vale, ¡genial!

Comment: mira las fotos tiene todo igual colocado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87613/discussion-between-sr-luis-and-ramon-albares).